# Is it haram to say Allahu Akbar in middle of sin but with different intention?

Tags: halal-haram, allah, sin

Assalamualaikum, I actually committed a sin and in middle of it, I said Allahu Akbar in middle but I said it with the intent of thanking Allah for a good thing and not for the sin, is it haram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prophet Muhammad (SAWW) once said:

> "The reward of deeds depends upon the intention and every person will
> get the reward according to what he has intended."

(*Sahih Bukhari, Kitab-ul-Imaan, Hadith No. 53*)

This hadith itself clears many misconceptions that we mostly have.